# I click in the last file and Windows select all

Tags: windows-7, selection

I'm trying to select one file and Windows selects all the files from the one I click to up.
The OS is W7 x64.
Same on desktop.
How I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any OS including Windows 7 will do this if you press Shift first.

Restart the computer, make sure you are not pressing the Shift key first, and see if the selection works.

If not, you may need to do a Windows 7 Repair Install from the Windows 7 DVD.

Comment: And check to make sure the shift key is not stuck. Smashing on both shift keys a few times may help “unstick” them if this is the case.

Comment: The behavior is that but I'm from my home(W10) connected to a remote W7 PC with AnyDesk. If I restart the PC I think I can't logging again remotely.

Comment: Can someone there restart the computer?

Comment: @John Maybe, but is a critical PC and I don't wanna share the password.

Comment: Maybe: https://reddit.com/r/AnyDesk/comments/d62fpl/ctrl_and_alt_keys_stuck_after_pressing_them/

Comment: It is possible that if someone restarts the PC , you may be able to connect and log in, then test it.

Comment: @JG7 The issue was resolved by it self but I think maybe I performed some key combination that unstuck the key on the remote PC.